# Bug with primeFaces Pagination ; infinite number of pages

Tags: jsf, primefaces, pagination

I'm currently working on lookups Table for a JSF Project. 
I have this table which will display a lot of codes later when linked to the database (for now it's hardcoded data) so I added primefaces 5.0 pagination. The problem here is that I have a Bug which happens when I created a Table for a specific code, change code , then go back to this table. [Look what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vj2r.png) :

[image]

An infinite number of pages with only 3 data... Every page are the same, and if I change the number of result per page, the problem disappear.

Here is the table in the code :

```
<h:form id="currentTable">
    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>
    <p:dataTable widgetVar="dataTableWidgetVar" var="lookupRow"
                 value="#{lookupsView.currentLookup.lookupRows}" editable="true"
                 style="margin-bottom:20px"
                 styleClass="tableWrapText"
                 paginator="true"
                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 200"
                 filteredValue="#{lookupsView.filteredLookupRows}">

        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" update=":currentTable:msgs" listener="#{lookupsView.onRowEdit}"/>
        <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" update=":currentTable:msgs"
                listener="#{lookupsView.onRowCancel}"/>
        <p:column headerText="XBRL Code" filterBy="#{lookupRow.xbrlCodeMember.memberValue}"
                  footerText="contains" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputText value="#{lookupRow.xbrlCodeMember.memberValue}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Client Code " filterBy="#{lookupRow.clientCode}" footerText="contains"
                  filterMatchMode="contains">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output"> <h:outputText value="#{lookupRow.clientCode}"/></f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{lookupRow.clientCode}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="XBRL Label" filterBy="#{lookupRow.xbrlCodeMember.memberDescription}"
                  footerText="contains" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputText value="#{lookupRow.xbrlCodeMember.memberDescription}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Client Label" filterBy="#{lookupRow.clientDescription}"
                  footerText="contains" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{lookupRow.clientDescription}"/></f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{lookupRow.clientDescription}"
                                                   style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column style="width:32px">
            <p:rowEditor/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Do you know where this bug could come from ?
It's on a Jboss7 server.

Comment: Did you define `rows` of `<p:dataTable>` in your real code?

Comment: @Tiny Yes everything is defined, all the data is showed correctly, can be saved, delete, ect...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, it happened because of the "#{lookupsView.filteredLookupRows}" variable, you have to clean by setting it to null, every time you change which table you display or it breaks somehow.